# notify-send with stderr in notification body if there is stderr

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line, notify-send

Suppose I have a command like:

```
foo() {
    echo a
    echo b >&2
    echo c
    echo d >&2
}
```

I use the following command to process stdout in terminal but send error via notify-send

```
foo 1> >(cat) 2> >(ifne notify-send "Error")
```

The issue i am having is, I want to view the stderr (in this case `b d`) as notify-send body.

I have tried:

```
foo 1> >(cat) 2> >(ifne notify-send "Error" "$(cat)")
foo 1> >(cat) 2> >(ifne notify-send "Error" "$(</dev/stdin)")
```

Nothing is working. What can be the solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your try with `"$(cat)"` you're almost there, but you need this `cat` to read from `ifne`, not along `ifne`.

In case of `ifne notify-send "Error" "$(cat)"`, `cat` reads from the same stream `ifne` does, but not simultaneously. The shell handling this part of code can run `ifne` only after `cat` exits (because only then it knows what `$(cat)` should expand to, i.e. what arguments `fine` should get). After `cat` exits, the stream is already depleted and `ifne` sees its input as empty.

This is a way to make a similarly used `cat` read from `ifne`:

```
foo 2> >(ifne sh -c 'exec notify-send "Error" "$(cat)"')
```

<sup>(I'm not sure what the purpose of your `1> >(cat)` was. I skipped it.)</sup>

Here `ifne` relays its input to the stdin of whatever it (conditionally) runs. It's `sh`, but everything this `sh` runs shares its stdin. Effectively `cat` reads from `ifne`. And similarly to your try, `exec notify-send` can be executed only after `cat` exits; so even if `notify-send` tried to read from its stdin, `cat` would consume everything first.

This method may fail if there is too much data passing through `cat`. Argument list cannot be arbitrarily long. And because `cat` will exit only after `foo` exits, the method works for `foo` that ever exits and generates not too many messages to its stderr.

Using `xargs` instead of `$(cat)` may be a good idea for long-running `foo` that *occasionally* generates a line of error. This is an example of such `foo`:

```bash
foo() {
    echo a
    echo b >&2
    sleep 10
    echo c
    echo d >&2
    sleep 20
}
```

The above solution is not necessarily good in case of this `foo` (try it). With `xargs` it's different. `foo` may even run indefinitely and you will be notified of errors (one line at a time) immediately. If your `xargs` supports `--no-run-if-empty` (`-r`) then you don't need `ifne`. This is an example command with `xargs`:

```
foo 2> >(xargs -r -I{} notify-send "Error" {})
```

<sup>(Note this `xargs` still interprets quotes and backslashes.)</sup>

Comment: Here is the final command which I was trying to run `maim --hidecursor --format=png --select | convert -  -units PixelsPerCentimeter -resample 300 -sharpen 12x6.0 - | tesseract -l eng stdin stdout 1> >(sed '$d' | perl -0777 -pe 's/^(\s*\n)+|(\s*\n)+$//g' | xclip -in -selection clipboard) 2> >(ifne sh -c 'exec notify-send "Tesseract Error:" "$(cat)"')`